# Do i need to be concerned with firebase refresh tokens with regard to sending cloud messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

**UPDATE:**

Upon **successful** **client** **authentication** with Firebase

iOS hybrid ionic Client receives an **FCM token** via the Firebase SDK and sends it to my cloud function which **stores the client token** into a document in a **user collection in firestore**

I have another **cloud function** that is responsible for **sending out push notifications** to individual users **via their FCM tokens** respectively, by retrieving the token from that same Firestore collection.

I have tested this to be working correctly, albeit without a refresh token, just the initial token.

**My question is, do i need to be subscribing to the** *FCM refresh token* **client side and updating that user document in my Firestore collection with the refresh token to ensure the firebase cloud push notification method is always retrieving a token that has not yet expired?** *(see method for retrieving refresh token referenced below)*

**Or could i** be retrieving the valid token from within the user object which is reachable via a cloud function server side with the  `firebase-admin` SDK method `admin.auth().getUser(uid)`?

To be clear, the client is a hybrid ionic/ios application and i am retrieving the token client side via the ionic native firebase method `Firebase.getToken()` which works in conjunction with the `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin:

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
constructor(private firebase: Firebase) { }
...
this.firebase.getToken()
  .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
  .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));

this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
   .subscribe(data => console.log(`User opened a notification ${data}`));

this.firebase.onTokenRefresh()
  .subscribe((token: string) => console.log(`Got a new token ${token}`));
```

Reference link --> [@ionic-native/firebase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase)

Answer (score 4):

The refresh token provided by Firebase Authentication is not going to be helpful for sending messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging.  What you will need to do is associate the device token provided by FCM to the UID of the signed in user.  Since users might be using multiple devices, it's customary to allow for multiple tokens to be associated with one UID.

The Firebase Admin SDK will not be helpful in getting tokens.  The token must be provided by the client.

Comment: I have been retrieving the initial token client side via the Firebase SDK, after login complete with the `getToken()` method, which works with regard to successfully sending/receiving FCM. So should i assume this is the device token?

Comment: What platform are you running on?  What's the full line of code (not just getToken, as there are several different types of tokens)?

Comment: Thanks and sorry, was trying to be brief, i will update question, client hybrid using @ionic-native/firebase with coresponding cordova firebase plugin, reference link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase

Comment: Sorry, I don't know those APIs.

Comment: Well, under the hood, ultimately the call is made via the Firebase iOS SDK, the ionic --> cordova API is just a wrapper, i will have a closer look and see if i can trace which method is ultimately triggered at the core and come back with another update.

Comment: Ah! — It does in-fact retrieve an FCM Token, so regardless of the API, really the question should be do i need to monitor the FCM Token for refresh, i will update the question further.

Comment: You should always respond to token changes and update your backend.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for taking the time, if you would like to update your answer to reflect this, i can mark it as correct, although is it possible to retrieve the current token server side as i noted?